# Make the user choose whether or not they want to restart the game

Tags: python

Start of code and i am making the user input the range of the numbers he wants to guess...If he guesses lower than the randomly selected number it prints to try again and guess higher and viceversa.

```
import random
import time
print("This is a guessing game!")        
print("")
user=input("Start by entering your name\n")
print("Hello "+user+"!")
print("Choose the end of the range by entering a number\n(Starting by default on 1)")
cho=input()
while  (float(cho))<1:
    print("Please enter another number , you have mistyped something")
    cho=input()
    if cho== range (1,9):
        continue
print("I am currently thinking a number from 1 to "+cho)
num=random.randint((float(1)),(float(cho)))
guess=input("Take a guess!\n")
while ((float(guess)) > (float(num))):
    print("Your number is higher than the one i thought.Guess lower")
    guess=float(input())
while float(guess) < float(num):
    print("Your number is lower than the one i thought.Guess higher")
    guess=float(input())
if float(guess)==float(num):
    print("You guessed right!Good Job!")
    print("The number was "+str(num))
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Bye")
    time.sleep(1 )
    exit()
```

After the user finishes here, i want to have an if and an elif so he can choose whether he wants or doesnt want to restart the "game"

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  You might want to edit it and make it clearer.

Comment: How about now? (Sorry am new to this site)

Comment: It's a bit clearer.  Still somewhat hard to figure out how to help.  In case you're wondering, I'm not the one that downvoted.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that's a bit more concise.  I also figured it'd probably make more sense to use integers, and only convert once.

```py
import random

print("This is a guessing game!\n")
user = input("Start by entering your name\n")

running = True
while running:
    print("Hello "+user+"!")
    print("Choose the end of the range by entering a number\n(Starting by default on 1)")
    cho=input()
    while  (float(cho))<1:
        print("Please enter another number , you have mistyped something")
        cho=input()
    print("I am currently thinking a number from 1 to "+cho)
    num = random.randint(1, int(cho))
    guess = int(input("Take a guess!\n"))
    while guess > num:
        guess = int(input("Your number is higher than the one i thought. Guess lower"))
    while guess < num:
        guess= int(input("Your number is lower than the one i thought. Guess higher"))
    if guess == num:
        print("You guessed right! Good Job!")
        print("The number was " + str(num))
        keep_playing = input("Do you want to keep playing? ")
        if keep_playing == "No" or keep_playing == "no":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            running = False
```

Comment: Thanks i will combine it with the other answer and it will be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can have an input statement asking "Do you want to keep playing or quit?"

This would be your entire code:

```py
import random
import time
loop = 5
while loop == 5:
    print("This is a guessing game!")        
    print("")
    user=input("Start by entering your name\n")
    print("Hello "+user+"!")
    print("Choose the end of the range by entering a number\n(Starting by default on 1)")
    cho=input()
    while  (float(cho))<1:
        print("Please enter another number , you have mistyped something")
        cho=input()
        if cho== range (1,9):
            continue
    print("I am currently thinking a number from 1 to "+cho)
    num=random.randint((float(1)),(float(cho)))
    guess=input("Take a guess!\n")
    while ((float(guess)) > (float(num))):
        print("Your number is higher than the one i thought.Guess lower")
        guess=float(input())
    while float(guess) < float(num):
        print("Your number is lower than the one i thought.Guess higher")
        guess=float(input())
    if float(guess)==float(num):
        print("You guessed right!Good Job!")
        print("The number was "+str(num))
        keep = input("Do you want to keep playing? ")
        if keep == "Yes" or keep == "yes":
            loop = 5
        elif keep == "No" or keep == "no":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            loop = 4
```

Hopefully this is what you wanted!

Comment: am just adding a else keep !=.... in case the user enters something wrong